# Cross Browser - Ajax or JQuery "recurring" call to Asp.Net MVC Controller Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, jquery

I need to have to make a call to a ASP.Net Controller Action every XX seconds (just to tell that I'm alive). The Action returns nothing.

Action Code:

```
public ActionResult StillOnline()
{
    // bla bla bla
    return new EmptyResult();
}
```

I understand the best way to make a "recurring" call is to use  "SetInterval(function, XXX)
but it seems that my trials work with one browser and not others.

My Current JQuery call:

```
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Url.Content("~/scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js") %>"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.setInterval(
                $.get('<%: Url.Action("StillOnline", "Account") %>'), 10000);
        </script>
```

This, for example, works well with Chrome (executes every 5 seconds) but not with IE (it only gets called once) and never throws an error.

QUESTION:

> What is the best Cross Browser way to
>   call an Controller Action on the
>   server that returns nothing ??

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to wrap your call into the DOM ready event as you are not manipulating any DOM elements and the following should work cross browser:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.setInterval(function() { 
        var url = '<%: Url.Action("Available", "ControllerName") %>';
        $.get(url);
    }, 10000);
</script>
```

Also notice the parenthesis `()` after the anonymous function declaration which you were missing in your initial declaration (the one passed to `setInterval` and not the one passed to `document.ready`).

Also it is a good idea to have your controller action always return something and not `null` (even if this something is an empty result):

```
public ActionResult Available()
{
    return new EmptyResult();
}
```

Comment: *"Also notice the parenthesis () after the anonymous function declaration."* Which I'm guessing is where the main problem was.

Comment: No need to pass nulls to `$.getJSON()` :)

Comment: *"No need to pass nulls to `$.getJSON()`"* In fact, no need for `getJSON` at all, since the return value is completely ignored. `$.ajax({url: '<%...%>'});` or `$.get('<%...%>')` would do it.

Comment: I just tried the first answer and this call works well with Chrome. 
I tested it with IE and it only gets called ONCE.

Let me try the other suggestions...

Comment: @Filu, try `$.get(url);` instead of `$.getJSON(url);`.

Comment: I think I'm not writing it right. So far I have


            <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            
            <script type="text/javascript">
                window.setInterval(function () {
                         $.ajax('<%: Url.Action("Available", "ControllerName") %>')}
                    , 10000);                
            </script>


and now NO browser is even executing the call once

Comment: Make sure jquery is properly included: `<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Url.Content("~/scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js") %>"></script>` by using url helpers.

Comment: Now Chrome executes ...every 5 seconds.
IE ..still nothing.

Comment: @Filu - `$.ajax()` doesn't take a single string argument, change it to `$.get()` for that:  `window.setInterval(function () { $.get('<%: Url.Action("Available", "ControllerName") %>')} , 10000);`

Comment: @Filu, did you try `$.get(url)`?

Comment: @Filu, what if instead of `$.get` you put `alert('foo');`?

Comment: Are you getting some error in IE? Try with a simple html page. I suspect the problem is somewhere else and now we are just guessing here which is not very efficient. Try narrowing down the problem.

Comment: UPDATE >>  alert('foo') EXECUTES on both browsers every 5 seconds.

Comment: OK, next step is to try to return something from the controller action: `return Content("foo", "text/plain");` and then `$.get(url, function(result) { alert(result); });`

Comment: @Darin ...something like

   window.setInterval(function {                        
                         var url = '<%: Url.Action("StillOnline", "Account") %>';
                         $.get(url, function(result) { alert(result); })}
                    , 10000);

Comment: @Filu, you still forgot the parenthesis after the function. You are also missing a `;` after the `$.get` function call.

Comment: OK ..so Chrome returns "foo"
IE returns "" (empty)

Comment: Yes I did add those before and still got empty on IE.

Comment: Is "Url.Action" the best way to call an Action on the Controller ??

Comment: `Url.Action` doesn't call an action on controller. It is a helper method which generates the url for this given action, it simply returns a string.

Comment: This is what I have now...


     window.setInterval(function () {
            var url = '<%: Url.Action("StillOnline", "Account") %>';
               $.get(url, function (result) { alert(result); });
          }
          , 10000);

Comment: Yes, this seems fine. Now how about your controller action?

Comment: It says:

        public ActionResult StillOnline()
        {
            if (SiteUser.IsAuthenticated)
                ActiveOnlineUser.ConfirmingOnline();

            return Content("foo", "text/plain");
        }

Comment: Try: `return Content("<html><body>foo</body></html>", "text/html");`, also try removing everything before it as it might throw some exception. Simply return this in your controller action, no other code at all.

Comment: Here is the strange part. The ActiveOnlineUser.ConfirmingOnline() ...stores an entry on the DB and on the Cache.

Then it returns your "foo" string.

When I run it with Chrome, I get the DB entry and then the "foo" back. When I run it with IR, I do NOT get the DB entry and get the "" return (emtpy).

???

Comment: So what happened when you removed all other code in your action and left with a single `return Content("foo", "text/plain");`?

Comment: I removed the ActiveOnlineUser.ConfirmingOnline() ... and still get "" on IE. I then change the return to the "html..." and still get "".

Comment: The IE dialog that returns the "" has the Yellow Triangle. Not sure if that matters.

Comment: IE still returns a Dialog with Yellow Triangle ..and empty message

Comment: could be the :

<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Url.Content("~/scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js") %>"></script>

Comment: No, that seems fine, unless of course the `jquery-1.4.1.min.js` file is missing at the specified location.

Comment: I changed it to "../../scripts ..." and now I get the Yellow triangle with "foo".

Comment: No, not necessary. Some browsers might be more tolerant to some type of errors in your scripts.

Comment: Darin.. do you mind if I create a quick sample later on and put it on some ftp..for you to see the code ??

Comment: Thanks...truly appreciated. This problem is killing me lately. I'll put it up later tonite. Believe it or not, I need to go to a safari now :--)

Comment: it's going to be a simple Asp.Net MVC 2 page with a partial view that executes this ping back to an Action that maybe puts a date on the session and return null (or "foo") ...

Talk to you later tonite !!!!

Comment: @Filu, just make sure to narrow down the problem. Don't expect me setting up a database or whatever to run the application. Just a plain ASP.NET MVC site created with VS2010 default template illustrating the problem.

Comment: @Darin ...while preparing the simple MVC application, it occurred to me that maybe the reason why that call was failing was because it was returning "" or empty or null or new EmptyResult.

So I change the return call to             
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");

...and it all works perfectly.

Now not sure if each PartialView Action should return the name of the Main View where they are located as result of each call ...but at least all browsers do execute the call every 5 seconds.

Any last thoughts on this one ???

Comment: Actually I need to understand this one. The PartialView is located on the MasterPage so it renders on all Views. The Action does a "return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home") which calls the Index Action on the Home Controller.

When I navigate to AboutView, the Action still get called (it's defined on the MasterPage) and the action calls the "Index" Action and NOT the About Action.

But after that Ping call ...the site still remains on the AboutView.

What am I missing here?
And does it make sense that we need to return a View for a PING procedure to execute successfuly??

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
return JSON(true);
```

in your Action. Your javascript is failing to parse JSON response it expects when you return null.

Comment: I found a fixed that not sure it's TEMP. Instead of returning null or Json(true) or new EmptyResult ...on my return, I RedirectToAction pointing to the Main View Action. 

With this change, both Chrome and IE work as expected firing the $.get{ ... } every 5 seconds. 

But I'm not sure if this is an overhead (to return an entire Main View) since my procedure supposed to be a simple PING to the server from a PartialView. 

What's your thoughts on that ??

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function DoCallBack() {
        var url = '<%: Url.Action("Available", "ControllerName") %>';
        $.getJSON(url, null, null);
}

window.setInterval("DoCallBack()", 10000);

</script>


public ActionResult Available()
{
    return "[]";
}
```

Comment: I'll continue to post this whenever I see it:  **Don't pass a string to `setInterval()` or `setTimeout()`**, pass a reference or anonymous function: `window.setInterval(DoCallBack, 10000);`

Comment: I wonder why not simply  $.get or $.post since you're not "returning" anything from that method as such other than just 'pinging'.

Comment: @Nick: Noted. But the reasons for that are?

Comment: @conqenator - it evaluates in a different context for example, if `DoCallBack` isn't a global function it won't work as a string, it's slower, security issues if you don't control it.